# How can I determine first call to WCF singleton service?

Tags: wcf, design-patterns, singleton

I'm writing a simple Windows WCF service as a singleton using the recommended InstanceContextMode.Single service behavior, e.g.:

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

My code looks like below (edited: revised to reflect changes suggested by commenters).  The question is, how can I tell from within my constructor  that the very first call to my service has been made?  That is, when the singleton has been instantiated for the first (and only) time?   Extensive testing via the debugger shows that the constructor is NEVER called.

[image]

I need to do some special processing on the first call to the service and the constructor seems like the logical place to do this.  However, I've tried placing some simple code in the constructor and can't even hit a breakpoint there (using remote debugging).  It's like the constructor is never actually called if I go with the *InstanceContextMode.Single* route (as opposed to the old classic method of having a static class and a static reference to an object, checking a reference to that object in the constructor to see if it's null, etc.)   **And, I wouldn't know what to check in the constructor even if I could place functional code there.**

Have I lost the ability to check for my first call by going the *InstanceContextMode.Single* route?

Comment: Pretty sure WCF won't instantiate the your server instance until a client actually makes a call to your service (creating a client proxy is not enough).  Try invoking it and see if the constructor is called.

Comment: Declare a static Boolean variable and set its initial value as false and check in your constructor if value is false then do your run only first time logic and  set that variable to true. That way you only run that logic once.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have indeed tried the static variable route, trying to check it in the constructor.  However, the constructor isn't being called even when clients make calls to the service.  I'm uploading a more complete picture of the code to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple WCF service (following the tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) with  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]. Default constructor got called only once as the service is marked as singleton. You can call your method SpinupQueueMonitor() from this constructor and can be sure of this executing once.

If this does not work, please try to create a static constructor. Static constructors are called only once. Please read the documentation for static constructor [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx). I hope this solves your issue.

Here is the sample code I used:

```
namespace WcfIis
{
    //Even though  the behavior is per call the static constructor will be called only once
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class Service1 : IService
    {
        public Service1()
        {

        }

        static Service1()
        {
            //SpinupQueueMonitor();
        }
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any issues.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to work through this.  Your answer with the static constructor is, I believe, in combination with a reply I received from Microsoft, the correct path.  You are correct that static constructors are only called once.  In addition, Microsoft says that for ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, the CORRECT BEHAVIOR IS THAT THE CONSTRUCTOR IS NEVEVER CALLED.  So going with PerCall, or perhaps the old-fashioned way of a static constructor and looking to see if the instance is null, is a better approach to investigate

Comment: Thank you.  Good to know the behavior on InstanceContextMode.Single.